# Catch event from item stored in a dependency property

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, dependency-properties

How do you catch an event from an object raised in a dependency property?

For example, normally I'd write something like this

```
Public Property foo1 as foo
   get
     return _foo
   end get
   set (value as foo)
     _foo = value
   end set
end property
Private WithEvents _foo as foo

Public Sub Foo_Handler() Handles _foo.SomeEvent
    'Do soemthing
End Sub
```

However you can't declare a dependency property as WithEvents. Any ideas

Comment: is it DP of custom control?

Comment: Yes, The DP holds an object of type ISaveView which has the following items: Sub Save(), Sub Cancel(), Event CloseView(), Event HasChanges(). I was able to work out a workaround by catching the OnChanged property of the DP, then saving a separate copy of the view in a private variable and capturing the events off of that. It works, but it just doesn't feel right and it's kinda hokey.

Comment: so, You can create another DP with type of Action,or ICommand. and when your DP updates state just raise Action,or Command. Another way you can create new type of custom Event and bind to it. so there are a lot of options, the choose is up to you

Comment: I added a bit more information in the answer below. Do you know of any articles that have more information on your comment above relating to "new type of Custom Event"? I'm afraid, I don't understand what you mean, but I'd like to research the option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with. I don't really like it and it doesn't feel right, but it works. If someone has a better solution please provide it as an answer. To provide a little more information about my use case, I have a dialog named OkCancelDialog. It's basically just a placeholder to present content to the end user. When the user clicks Ok, the Save method of ISaveView is called and conversely when the Cancel button is clicked, it calls the Cancel method. The problem I ran into is that the save method usually has to save the item asynchronously. Originally I had marked the save method as a function that returned a boolean (which closed the dialog if true), but the problem was that if something went wrong during the save, the OkCancelDialog would already be closed. So now, I call the Save method and provided everything saves properly in the View, it raises the event CloseView, which I then capture in the OKCancelDialog to close the dialog.

I would love to hear other options for accomplishing this.

Interface ISaveView:

```
Public Interface ISaveView
    Sub Cancel()
    Sub Save()
    Event CloseView()
    Event HasChanges()
End Interface
```

Class with DP:

DP:

```
Public ViewProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("View", GetType(ISaveView), GetType(OkCancelDialog), New PropertyMetadata(Nothing, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnViewChanged)))
```

CLR Property:

```
#Region "View"
    Public Property View As ISaveView
        Get
            Return DirectCast(GetValue(ViewProperty), ISaveView)
        End Get
        Set(value As ISaveView)
            SetValue(ViewProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub OnViewChanged()
        _view = View
        OnPropertyChanged("View")
    End Sub
    Private WithEvents _view As ISaveView

    Private Sub View_HasChanges() Handles _view.HasChanges
        okButton.IsEnabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub View_CloseView() Handles _view.CloseView
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
#End Region
```